# Aligning Left/Center/Right LinearLayout - Android

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, alignment

This should be pretty easy, but since I am new in android development I am asking. I basicaly want to create a static menu bar at the bottom of my avtivity with simple buttons (previous / home / next). However I have problem in aligning those since **android:layout_alignParentRight="true"** does not seem to do the work. I have also tried out gravity, but neither that works.My current code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/previousButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomBar"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomBar"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: here is all my layout xml file:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="menelaos.example.com.geolearning.QuizActivity">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/quizTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</TableLayout>
<TableLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:id="@+id/answerTableLayout"
       android:layout_below="@+id/quizTableLayout">
</TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout> </ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/previousButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).

Try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previousButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/previousButton"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

try this then:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/bottomBar">
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/previousButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/previousButton"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, so if I understood correctly:
You want a Layout composed by a Scroll View and a View in the bottom of the screen with two buttons, one aligned to the left of the screen and the other aligned to the right.
I think the following layout suggestion can work out for you. Nevertheless, without seeing your current layout I cannot clearly understand how you want your layout to be.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
    />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previousButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="New Button" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 3**

In order to have a 3rd button just add the XML below after the last Button view:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Center" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/previousButton" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/nextButton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
```

I've added the `marginLeft` and `marginRight`so that the buttons have a distance between them, as I think this is what you want.

Comment: This wont do the work since the layout is not on the bottom of the device wrapping my content, as I want

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood... You want the RelativeLayout on the bottom? And what layout will you put above it? I'm not sure if that's possible, have two layouts in one activity...

Comment: I am having a ScrollView above my layout. It must be possible since many applications have that kind of layouts. Here is a link of one program: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EI4MP0DpFeE. Check minute: 2:09 the bottom menu bar. This is what i want

Comment: this wont work too since RelativeLayout is not at the bottom. Plus the buttons cant get aligned as I want them to be

Comment: Could you please provide your layout xml? I'm assuming the RelativeLayout is the root Layout and the LinearLayout is the one at the bottom

Comment: I did edit my question so you can see all my code. I will check out your second edit now.

Comment: amazing your EDIT 2 seems to work. I just wanna ask you how we can add a third button and align it in the center? In your answer you provide 2 buttons. They are right. I just want a third button in the middle aligned too

Comment: and one other question mate if you want to answer it. I want this RelativeLayout to use it in other forms too, is there any way to save it as xml and reference it via other .xml files (without writing java I mean)

Comment: Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/) site, which has well-documented guides for those who aren't still experts in Android

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the xml attribute alignParentBottom in a LinearLayout. It works for a RelativeLayout.

Secondly, the attribute gravity only position the content of the tag ( it will put the buttons in the center of the page verticalty)

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/previousButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"


        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your code throws exception: "@+id/bottombar is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout"

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to make each button take the same width and occupy the total width of the parent layout:

In buttons, change to `android:layout_width="0dp"`
and add `android:layout_weight="1"`

This will distribute all the buttons with homogeneous width.